# Moving Two UIImageView's with UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uislider

I'm trying to move two UIImageView's together in accordance with a UISlider. Here is a picture for a better understanding:

[image]

When the slider's ball is slid to the far left (a value of zero), then only green shall show. When it's slid to the far right (a value of 600), only red should show. If the value of the slider is 480, it should show 80% of the red picture and 20% of the green. The code I'm using to try and achieve this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.slider.maximumValue = 600;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

    [imageViewLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(slider.value - 50, imageViewLeft.frame.origin.y,imageViewLeft.frame.size.width,imageViewLeft.frame.size.height)];

        [imageViewRight setFrame:CGRectMake(slider.value + 50, imageViewRight.frame.origin.y,imageViewRight.frame.size.width,imageViewRight.frame.size.height)];

}
```

This is working decently, but the second I change the slider, the red image (named imageViewLeft) shrinks while the imageViewRight remains the same size. I can't for the life of me figure out why (I'm still very new with programming and iOS in general). Does anyone know what I should change or how to best accomplish this?

Comment: How wide are your image views? Are they each full screen width (320)?

Comment: @rdelmar They are well over full screen, each one is 481 x 568.

Comment: Where did you come up with the value of 50? It doesn't correlate with what you say you're trying to do. When the slider is in the middle (value of 300), the green view's left edge will be 350, which is off the right side of the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to leave the green background full screen and just adjust the red view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve more or less the same thing by keeping the green background full screen and only adjusting the red view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.slider.maximumValue = 600;

    imageViewRight.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    [imageViewLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,(self.slider.value/self.slider.maximumValue)*sliderimageViewRight.frame.size.width,imageViewRight.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Or if you'd still rather have both views edge-to-edge then you can do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.slider.maximumValue = 600;
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    [imageViewLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,(self.slider.value/self.slider.maximumValue)*self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [imageViewRight setFrame:CGRectMake(imageViewLeft.frame.size.width, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width-imageViewLeft.frame.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.red setFrame:CGRectMake(slider.value+50-self.view.frame.size.width, imageViewLeft.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width, imageViewLeft.frame.size.height)];
[self.green setFrame:CGRectMake(slider.value+50, imageViewRight.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width, imageViewRight.frame.size.height)];
```

And set maximum slider value to its width:

```
self.slider.maximumValue = self.slider.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that makes sense. However, the code is still doing basically the same thing, should I be putting 50 as the value, or do you know what else I may be doing wrong?